# The Riemann class and its group of automorphisms

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

as far as I know, the Selberg class is believed to be the maximal class of meromorphic complex functions for which the Riemann hypothesis holds. A compelling fact is that this class is defined by a set of axioms each of which appears to be necessary to make the zeros in the critical strip lie on the critical line. An interesting question would thus be "is this set of axioms sufficient?" An attempt to answer it would be to define a "Riemann class" as the set of all meromorphic complex functions for which the Riemann hypothesis actually holds. Then one could try to define the group of automorphims of this "Riemann class" and elucidate its structure.
My question is: if it ever happened that this group of automorphisms of the "Riemann class" were isomorphic to the group of automorphisms of the Selberg class that I defined assuming Selberg's orthonormality conjecture, could one deduce that the Riemann hypothesis eventually holds for some functions of the Selberg class?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using Weierstrass products -- or even polynomials like $p_t=s-(1/2+it)$! -- it is trivial to construct uncountably many meromorphic functions, all of which zeros are on any specific line in the plane.